# Socket error from within Rails app in Docker container connecting to remote MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker

I have a rails app (running in production mode) in a docker container linked to another container running a MySQL server instance. The app itself is running under nginx/passenger as the "app" user. I've configured the production database under rails as follows:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PRODUCTION_DATABASE'] %>
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['MYSQL_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PASS'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['MYSQL_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PORT'] %>
```

with the the environment variables set when the container is ran. I can execute the database-related rake commands (migrate, reset, etc.) successfully when attached to the container (running as root). However, when I try to load the app in the browser I get the following error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:456:in `real_connect'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:456:in `connect'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:108:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:36:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:36:in `mysql_connection'
```

Does anyone know what could cause the mysql adapter to incorrectly treat the connection as local in this context, but remote when running the rake commands?

Comment: Note that I've also tried this with postgres with the same behavior: everything works under root with rake commands, but the actual app cannot connect to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually caused by the environment variables set as arguments at run time not being set in the rails process. My web server (nginx) clears out all environment variables before running, thus flushing the ones set by docker.